# How to continue normal flow of execution in Android studio while dubging, when cursor is navigate to the subclasses?

Tags: java, debugging, android-studio

In android studio while debugging application , when i attach debugger for extended class, cursor is navigate to the sub classes like (activity.java,Thread.java) ,so how to prevent this one to continue the normal flow of execution? particular this happens when i set more than one break point and when i debug same code second time, so my question is, how to prevent this one to perform normal flow of execution?

Comment: i do not wanted to navigate my cursor in sub classes

Comment: When i navigate to the sub class how can i return to the main flow any shortcut key?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run > Resume Program, Shortcut key is F9.